# Syntax error in http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

I'm working from VS10 and have a master page that loads jQuery via:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

At my page's load firebug and dev tools (IE9) both report an error:

[Firebug]
    [Break On This Error] "triggered": }; jquery...sdoc.js (line 1527)
[dev tools]
    SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
    jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js, line 1527 character 15

This is not happening on every page that uses the MasterPage - I haven't drilled into what feature is causing the error. Intellisense is working (though i haven't spent a great deal of time with this jQuery version yet).

I'm concerned that this error will terminate subsequent scripts, though again, things (ajax transactions) _seem to continue to process normally. I need to know how much attention to pay to this error flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be including jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js.  That is intended to be loaded by the IDE to allow for intellisense.  It shouldn't be loaded on your page.

Comment: I've wrapped the calls in the 'if (false)' construct and still see the error on the rendered page. What's the syntax you are using? thx

Comment: What I mean is, don't include that file. In the top of your example, it says you're including <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> on your page.  That script is not intended to be embedded on a page.  That is used strictly by Visual Studio to provide intellisense for JavaScript.